# Button click event to affect a different window

Tags: c#, wpf, events, button, click

I have a WPF application (Window 1) with a ScrollViewer on it.  I have a second window that is apart of the same WPF application, that has a button on it.

When I click the button on the second window, I want it to add an item to the ScrollViewer on the first window.

How can I accomplish this?  Sorry if this is vague, I'm not sure how to ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need a `DispatcherTimer` and you'll have to use `StackPanel` instead of `Grid`. You'll also need to declare a `public static bool` on `Window1`. Then, when the button on `Window2` is clicked, the `bool` is set to `True` which means to execute a void that will add the object to the `StackPanel` or the `Scroll Viewer`

### XAML

<sup>**Window1.xaml**</sup>

First, you will need to change `Grid` to `StackPanel`. Assuming that you have a `ScrollViewer` with the name `scrollViewer1`, and `Margin = "37,36,58,36"`, You should try the following

Change the following

```xml
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Margin="37,36,58,36" Name="scrollViewer1" />
</Grid>
```

to

```xml
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
    <ScrollViewer Margin="37,36,58,36" Name="scrollViewer1" />
</StackPanel>
```

So that you would be able to use a `StackPanel` instead of a `Grid` of a name `stackPanel`

---

### C#

<sup>**Window1.xaml**</sup>

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public static bool AddItem = false; //This must be public and static so that it can be called from your second Window
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void AddToScrollViewer()
        {
            Button _Object = new Button(); //Create a new object, change button to the UIElement you would like to be
            stackPanel.Children.Add(_Object); //Add the UIElement to the StackPanel
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer(); //Initialize a new timer object
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick); //Link the Tick event with dispatcherTimer_Tick
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); //Set the Timer Interval
            dispatcherTimer.Start(); //Start the Timer
        }

        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (AddItem)
            {
                AddItem = false;
                AddToScrollViewer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>**Window2.xaml**</sup>

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window2.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        public Window2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1.AddItem = true;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be for your second Form to have a [custom Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx) that passes the information to your MainWindow.

This is a quick proof of concept, see if it works for you.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**
1 scrollviewer 1 stackpanel in the scrollviewer and 1 button:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Window2 secondWindow;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            secondWindow = new Window2();
            secondWindow.RaiseCustomEvent += new Window2.myCustomEventHandler(secondWindow_RaiseCustomEvent);
            secondWindow.ShowDialog();
        }

        void secondWindow_RaiseCustomEvent(object sender, myCustomEventArgs e)
        {
            Label lbl= new Label();
            lbl.Content = string.Copy(e.retrieveString);
            ((StackPanel)scrollViewer1.Content).Children.Add(lbl);
        }
    }
}
```

**Window2.xaml.cs**
1 Button

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window2.xaml
    /// </summary>

   public partial class Window2 : Window
   {
        public delegate void myCustomEventHandler(object sender, myCustomEventArgs e);
        public event myCustomEventHandler RaiseCustomEvent;
        String myStatement = "Hello World";
        public Window2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myCustomEventArgs ea = new myCustomEventArgs( myStatement);
            RaiseCustomEvent(sender, ea);

        }
    }

    public class myCustomEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public myCustomEventArgs(string s)
        {
            myString = s;
        }
        private string myString;
        public string retrieveString
        {
            get { return myString; }
        }
    }
}
```